# Knockout.js foreach not working for second or more elements

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to bind an array with a table, if I have this:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: Applicants, visible: Applicants().length > 0">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <p data-bind="text:FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()" />
        <img data-bind="attr:{src: URL}" width="100px" height="100px" alt="test" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

the img tag won't be generated, just omit from the display.

Have to have another `<td>` wrap `<img>` to display it. Why?

---

Ok, @Stokedout is right, after trying with `</p>` instead of using closed tag `<p .... />`, it works. 
So if the tag could have value but is closed without any value then knockout won't work for the rest of tags..

Example:

Will work: -- Both first name and last name will display.

```
      <p data-bind="text: FirstName"></p>
      <p data-bind="text: LastName"></p>
```

Will NOT work: -- ONLY first name will display

```
      <p data-bind="text: FirstName"/>
      <p data-bind="text: LastName"/>
```

I AM NOT SURE WHY!

Comment: Can you include your viewModel? It could be something to do with the closing paragraph tag. Try end it like </p> . Also I'm surprised first name and last name render the way you've coded it. Computed variables are usually a cleaner way of doing this

Comment: Do you even have any `Applicants` to show?  You'll need to show us more your code.

Comment: I don't have the full code here while I could post tmr while on my work machine. But the point is if I put the img tag into another <td> tag, then it works....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
<p data-bind="text:FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()" />
<img data-bind="attr:{src: URL}" width="100px" height="100px" alt="test" />
```

Without a closing tag, the img will be treated as the content the paragraph. For self-closed P element, the browser can infer that the paragraph has ended by the start of the next paragraph.

When you bind using this:

```
data-bind="text:FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()"
```

KO will try to set text to your P element and it clear the previous content.

Solution is very simple, just add a closing tag:

```
<p data-bind="text:FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()"></p>
<img data-bind="attr:{src: URL}" width="100px" height="100px" alt="test" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `<p>` element must have full element syntax.

```
<p data-bind="text:FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()"></p>
```

Without it, the HTML becomes:

```
<p data-bind="text:...">
    <img ... />
</p>
```

So the `img` becomes the contents of the `p` element and gets overwritten by the `text` binding.

Comment: yes, it's the issue, but why? if you have a <img/> tag, then it works for the rest tags after <img> but not <span/>, </p> and so on. Yes, I should use tbody and I switched to <div>.

Comment: Check my answer to know why :)

Comment: I just added the explanation, but you got to it first.